# Operator not found on SearchBooleanField

Tags: netsuite

I'm new to the SuiteTalk API, but from what I can tell, this query SHOULD work [(using the netsuite gem for ruby)](https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite):

```
memorized_invoices = NetSuite::Records::Transaction.search({ criteria: { basic: [{ field: 'type', operator: 'anyOf', type: 'SearchEnumMultiSelectField', value: ["_invoice"]}, {field: 'memorized', value: true}]}})
```

But all I receive is a missing operator on SearchBooleanField:

```
D, [2013-10-15T16:23:10.607161 #5131] DEBUG -- : HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (curb)
Savon::SOAPFault: (soapenv:Server.userException) org.xml.sax.SAXException: operator not found on {urn:core_2011_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}SearchBooleanField
```

Any suggestions as to why it's missing an operator on the SearchBooleanField? From your example on the main markdown page (search for: # no operator for booleans), a boolean field shouldn't need an operator.

I've done a basic google search, and haven't found much, except a few PHP examples that show that they use the operator 'is', which doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

I've also opened this question as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite/issues/33). Thanks!

Comment: It appears that this is specific to the netsuite gem I linked to in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug found in the gem implementation of the netsuite library. If anyone else ever runs into this problem, see how we're solving it on [the issue on the repository](https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite/issues/33#issuecomment-26417840).

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `operator` property from your filter for the `memorized` field:

```
{field: 'memorized', operator: 'is', value: true}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. There is no operator for SearchBooleanField, which is exactly the point of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look at the Schema Browser.

You are correct - no operator appears to be needed.

```
<complexType name="SearchBooleanField">
    <sequence>
        <element name="searchValue" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Why not create a saved search in the UI that represents the records you want to process? Just execute the search and loop through the results.

I don't know about the Ruby Gem, but executing a saved search via web services is fairly simple.

```
// create search object
TransactionSearchAdvanced tsa = new TransactionSearchAdvanced();

//set saved search id
tsa.savedSearchId="100";

// perform the search
NetSuiteService nss = new NetSuiteService(); 
SearchResult result = nss.search(tsa);
```

Comment: I wonder why I'm getting an Operator Not Found error on this call if no operator is acceptable. I'll look into the saved search, but the added dependency against the installation setup is not ideal. Any ideas why the call would fail if I don't set an operator?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like I do not have permissions to create a saved search in the GUI.

Comment: You can either have someone create the search for you and grant you permission to run it, or ask you admin to grant you access to create saved searches. They are super helpful, so it's really easy to build a case to have the permission. If you run your code based off a saved search, you don't have to touch the code to change what data is returned by your call - you just manipulate the saved search. Much easier.